# Prove that $(e^{i\lambda A})^\dagger=e^{-i\lambda A^\dagger}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

> Prove $$(e^{i\lambda A})^\dagger=e^{-i\lambda A^\dagger}$$ where $A$ is an operator.

Can anyone explain how to go about this question? Writing it as a power series gets confusing.

So basically I get:
$(e^{i\lambda A})^\dagger=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ({(i\lambda)}^n\frac{A ^n}{n!})^\dagger=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ({(-i\lambda)}^n\frac{(A^\dagger)^n}{n!})=e^{-i\lambda A^\dagger}$
Is this right?

Comment: Writing as a power series might be confusing, but it's still the way to go.

Comment: Why does it get confusing? Can you try to write it as a power series so we can see what the problem you're having is?

Comment: @LeandroM. can you please take a look at my answer above? I edited the question.

Comment: Yep, that is correct (assuming $\lambda$ is real, of course).

Comment: @LeandroM. how do I solve it if $\lambda$ is complex?

Comment: You just think of it like it's a $1 \times 1$ matrix. Then $\lambda^\dagger = \lambda^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Prove $$(e^{i\lambda A})^\dagger=e^{-i\lambda A^\dagger}$$ where $A$ is an operator.
>
> Can anyone explain how to go about this question? Writing it as a
>   power series gets confusing.
>
> So basically I get: $(e^{i\lambda A})^\dagger=\sum_{n=0}^\infty({(i\lambda)}^n\frac{A ^n}{n!})^\dagger=\sum_{n=0}^\infty({(-i\lambda)}^n\frac{(A^\dagger)^n}{n!})=e^{-i\lambda A^\dagger}$ 
>   Is this right?

Yes, it is "right" (assuming that $\lambda$ is real). But you might want to explain the steps, i.e. how you go from one equality to another. For example, you made some assumptions: 
$$
(\hat X+\hat Y)^\dagger=\hat X^\dagger + \hat Y^\dagger
$$
$$
(ix\hat X)^\dagger=-ix\hat X^\dagger
$$
etc.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is complex how would I solve the question then?

Comment: You should be able to figure this out on your own. Ask yourself: What action does $\dagger$ have on $x$ if $x$ is a complex number...

Comment: It'll simple become a complex conjugate so $\lambda$ will be $\lambda$*?

Comment: yep, that's right